# if column name = this, then search for a row >0 and change symbol, in QGIS

Tags: qgis, definition-query

Excuse me as I am new to GIS. I am using QGIS to do two things. Firstly, from a csv master file, I have plotted points on a map based on their geo-reference and graduated their colour based on the level of species diversity. Cool.

The next thing I wish to do is change the symbology based on the presence of certain species. The data is formatted as follows, each row is a 10m x 10m plot in the field and each column is a species name (500+ columns). Where a species is present in a plot, the value is > 0.

I would like to use a list of species names located in another file to search through each column name (field label?), and where the name matches, search each row/plot for a value > 0. If the column contains a value > 0, the symbol of the point corresponding to that row would change. I.e. If a species is found in a plot, the symbol changes to indicate its presence.

I imagine this is quite a straight-forward task, however, I cannot find any information or guides for how one might achieve this. This is likely due to my poor understanding of GIS terminology. While I am a competent coder in programs such as R, this is my first forray into GIS.

I have acheived what I wanted by first processing and formatting the data in R using this code:

```
setwd("~/Uni/Data/")
CMRA_feb2014_uniform <- read.csv("~/Uni/Data/CMRA_feb2014_uniform.csv", stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
OrchidNVSNames <- read.csv("~/Uni/Data/OrchidNVSNames.csv", stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
CMRA_feb2014_Orchids = data.frame(NULL,NULL,NULL)
SpeciesCount = 0
i=1
j=1
k=1
x = 1
for(i in 1:length(CMRA_feb2014_uniform)){
    for(j in 1:length(OrchidNVSNames$NVSCode)){    
        if(identical(names(CMRA_feb2014_uniform[i]),OrchidNVSNames[j,1]))  {      
            for(k in 1:nrow(CMRA_feb2014_uniform)){
                if(CMRA_feb2014_uniform[k,i] > 0){          
                    CMRA_feb2014_Orchids[x,1] <- as.integer(CMRA_feb2014_uniform[k,"Plot"]) #Plot number
                    CMRA_feb2014_Orchids[x,2] <- OrchidNVSNames[j,"NVSCode"]
                    CMRA_feb2014_Orchids[x,3] <- OrchidNVSNames[j,"SpeciesName"]
                    CMRA_feb2014_Orchids[x,4] <- CMRA_feb2014_uniform[k,i]          
                    for(l in 1:length(CMRA_feb2014_uniform)){
                        CMRA_feb2014_Orchids[x,4+l] <- CMRA_feb2014_uniform[k,l]
                     }
                x = x+1
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
colnames(CMRA_feb2014_Orchids)<- c("OrchidPlot","OrchidNVSCode","OrchidName","Orchid%C",c(names(CMRA_feb2014_uniform)))
write.csv(CMRA_feb2014_Orchids, file = "CMRA_feb2014_OrchidData.csv", row.names = FALSE)
```

I then imported the final cvs as a layer, and styled the points using point displacement.[image: Produced map]

While I have achieved what I wanted, it would be great to know if there is a way to do this within QGIS, or be pointed in a direction where I may gain the background to carry out such tasks

Comment: It's unclear which symbol you're trying to change. You have N species for 1 plot (point), right? Your plot has one symbology, but it seems like you're talking about changing 500 variables (species) for each plot. Remember: 1 symbol - 1 feature.

Comment: So for each plot (point, n = 130), if species_x > 0 = true, change the symbol from a circle to a star.

There is 500 potential species in each plot, but I am only interested in identifying the plots which have a subset of those 500 species.

Comment: do you want to have as many maps (circle/star) as species in your another file?

Comment: That would be useful to deliniate which species are where, however, for now I would be happy to just have one different symbol to illustrate that a species from the another file is present

Comment: so if ANY of the species from the file is 'present' the plot is represented by star?